# Scaffolding with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm following along with "Professional ASP.NET MVC 4" and trying to generate a controller from a model using Entity Framework. My Model looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class MusicStoreModels
    {
        public class Album
        {
            public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
            public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
            public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
            public virtual string Title { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
            public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
            public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
            public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
        }

        public class Artist
        {
            public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Genre
        {
            public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
            public virtual string Name { get; set; }
            public virtual string Description { get; set; }
            public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I right click my *Controllers* folder and choose *Add > Controller* I select **"MVC controller with read/write action and views, using Entity Framework"** as my template and **"Album (MvcMusicStore.Models)"** as my Model class. The book tells me to select **"new data context..."** and name it **"MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreDBContext"**.

Everything looks OK and I have saved and built my solution prior to performing the above actions. However, I get an error message saying

```
There was an error generating 'MvcMusicStore.Models.MusicStoreDBContext'.
Try rebuilding your project.'
```

I'm at a bit of a loss. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is **every** property `virtual`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. To quote the book: "You might also notice that every property is virtual. I discuss why the properties are virtual later in this chapter. For now, these three simple class definitions are your starting models, and include everything you need to scaffold out a controller and some views and even create a database."

Comment: `virtual` properties assist with lazy loading of entities.

Comment: I've installed Entity Framework 5 via NuGet in Visual Studio 2012 but still having the same problem when I try to generate my Controller. Am I missing a using statement somewhere? Feeling pretty frustrated.

Comment: I wouldn't have the primitive properties (int, string , decimal) as virtual, there's no point in lazy-loading them.

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms sound a lot like this issue:
http://www.rhysgodfrey.co.uk/archive/2011/04/20/mvc3-tools-update-and-entity-framework-4-1-error.aspx

I would suggest uninstalling all versions of Entity Framework, re-installing the latest version through NuGet, and regenerating your EF context from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I not very up on C# (i think it is C# code - but dont quote me on that).....

Well after pasting your code in a new project i notice the line that says

```
Using System.Data.Entity;
```

Is flagged as an error,
And some further research shows that a refrence is POSSIBLY missing in inyour config.sys file...

Re: http://forums.asp.net/t/1381740.aspx/1